# How To Bind Mouse action?

Tags: c#-3.0, mouse

I have Added following code to add `Mouse` Gestures in command binding but it looks like Keyboard shortcuts are working but Mouse shortcut isn't working:

```
      gestures = new InputGestureCollection
      {
        new KeyGesture(Key.Enter, ModifierKeys.Control), new MouseGesture(MouseAction.MiddleClick, ModifierKeys.Control)
      };
      zoomChartToFitCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Zoom To Fit", "zoomChartToFit", typeof(ZoomCommands), gestures);
```